# How to configure Facet Advanced Range?

Tags: search

I'm lost on how to configure advanced ranges in Facet API displays. I see [this page](https://drupal.org/node/1286068), which supposedly quotes from the README

> For example [100 200] will produce a range between 100 and 200.
>   For example [100 *] will produce a range of "100 and above"

I've configured my ranges like this:

[image: failed config]

But the drop down menu appears like this:

[image: facet api range fail]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the documentation is just a lie...

https://drupal.org/node/2126017

These values worked:

```
0-800
800-1000
1000-1200
...
1800-2000
2000-
```